# Why won't my dialog show properly when I set its parent on instantiation?

Tags: qt, pyqt, show

In the attached example script, why won't the MyDialog instance show properly when I set MyDialog's parent to self on line 20 instead of leaving it blank?  First I thought the shortcut had stopped working somehow, but obviously that's not the case.

In this case it doesn't really make any difference whether the parent is set, but in my real case I need the parent to be set.

Am I missing something obvious here?

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        label = QLabel(self)
        label.setText("World")
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.my_dialog = MyDialog()
        #self.my_dialog = MyDialog(self)
        label = QLabel(self)
        label.setText("Hello")
        self.setCentralWidget(label)
        shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Tab), self, self.show_my_dialog)
        shortcut.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
        self.show()
    def show_my_dialog(self):
        md = self.my_dialog
        if md.isVisible():
            md.hide()
            print 'hide'
        else:
            md.show()
            print 'show'

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    main_window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't show properly?

Comment: It doesn't show at all. The script outputs `'hide'` and `'show'` respectively to the console when `Tab` is pressed, so the shortcut works but `md.show()` doesn't seem to have any effect. I get the same behavior on Windows and OS X. Interestingly enough, after removing the `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` line the dialog will show properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my machine (Kubuntu 11.10) it's working.
If Dialog's parent is None - it opens another frameless window, and i have two entries in taskbar. If i close the main window, dialog remains.

If you are using Windows - the behavior you described might be related to it. Maybe the window is shown, it's just behind other windows?

If Dialog's parent is the main window - the frameless dialog is shown inside the main window - in the top left corner near the label.

You might be interested in this [info](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdialog.html#details):

> A dialog window is a top-level window mostly used for short-term tasks
> and brief communications with the user. QDialogs may be modal or
> modeless. QDialogs can provide a return value, and they can have
> default buttons. QDialogs can also have a QSizeGrip in their
> lower-right corner, using setSizeGripEnabled().
>
> Note that QDialog (an
> any other widget that has type Qt::Dialog) uses the parent widget
> slightly differently from other classes in Qt. A dialog is always a
> top-level widget, but if it has a parent, its default location is
> centered on top of the parent's top-level widget (if it is not
> top-level itself). It will also share the parent's taskbar entry.
>
> Use
> the overload of the QWidget::setParent() function to change the
> ownership of a QDialog widget. This function allows you to explicitly
> set the window flags of the reparented widget; using the overloaded
> function will clear the window flags specifying the window-system
> properties for the widget (in particular it will reset the Qt::Dialog
> flag).